# Connect markers in lineplot seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, visualization, line-plot

I have a dataset as:

```
road,rate
DP,95.78
TR,95.02
SP,86.02
HD,45
SP_HD, 86
```

and I use seaborn to visualize a line plot like this:

```
def line_plot_compression_rate():
    label_text = pd.read_csv("comp_rate.csv")
    plot = sns.lineplot(x="road", y="rate", hue="road", style="road",
                        markers=True, data=label_text)

    plt.show()


line_plot_compression_rate()
```

Produced result:

[image]
How can I connect the markers with a line? Also, is it possible to enlarge the markers size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
plot = sns.lineplot(x="road", y="rate", data=df, sort=False)
sns.lineplot(x="road", y="rate", hue="road", style="road", hue_order=df.road,markers=True, data=df, ax=plot)
plt.show()
```

Figure:

[image]

And to **change markers and line size**:

```
paper_rc = {'lines.linewidth': 3, 'lines.markersize': 10}                  
sns.set_context("paper", rc = paper_rc) 

plot = sns.lineplot(x="road", y="rate", data=df, sort=False)
plot  = sns.lineplot(x="road", y="rate", hue="road", style="road",
             hue_order=df.road,markers=True,sizes=600,
             data=df, ax=plot)
```

Figure:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. it works. Do you know how to enlarge markers size and the line width?